# How do I change my Submit Button Text in the Field Notes Theme for Tumblr?

Tags: html, css, submit-button

```
{block:SubmissionsEnabled}<li><a href="/submit">{SubmitLabel}</a></li>{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
```

This is all I really know about it. This is the only mention of Submit in the whole CSS/HTML business.

Answer (score 0):

Change the text that says

> {SubmitLabel}